# Why does emacs start out with such a goofy tab spacing here?

Tags: emacs, octave, mode

This appears on a Linux version of emacs 24.3.1.

Fire up a buffer, enter `octave-mode` (you may need to install from package), and enter something like this:

```
function foo = bar(x,y)
```

Now, if you go to the line below, and hit `TAB` to start bashing away, the cursor will jump 8 spaces in!

After you recover from the heart palpitations and hyperventilation, you notice that if you hit `TAB` after typing some stuff, Emacs comes to its senses and brings the whole line back to 2 space indent. The rest of the lines below that will behave.

What is the thinking or reason for this behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it is possible to program Emacs to do just about anything, I just adjust or fix whatever I need to and rarely look for the rationale of default settings.

```
(add-hook 'octave-mode-hook (lambda ()
  (setq indent-tabs-mode t)
  (setq tab-stop-list (number-sequence 2 200 2))
  (setq tab-width 2)
  (setq indent-line-function 'insert-tab) ))
```

Comment: It's a vicious cycle--users can fix any of Emacs's "mistakes", so there's less pressure to fix them in Emacs!